# problem to show layers in legend using arcgis silverlight api

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I tried to create a simple webgis with silverlight.
Software that I used to make the application:  ArcGIS Desktop 10 (without sp), ArcGIS Server 10, Silverlight 4, Microsoft blend 4, and Visual Studio 2010 sp1.
We generally use the code below to add layers to map:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="Map" >
        <esri:Map.Layers>
              <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="samplewebgis" 
                    Url="http://m-pc/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer" />        
        </esri:Map.Layers>
  </esri:Map>
```

But when i use the code, the map legend shows no layers. then I tried the code below:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="Map"   Grid.RowSpan="3">                                  

      <esri:FeatureLayer  ID="xx" Url="http://m-pc/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer/0"/> 
      <esri:FeatureLayer  ID="yy" Url="http://m-pc/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer/1" /> 

</esri:Map>
```

This code works properly and legend show layers. Why can't I use esri:map.layers and why can't the legend show layers of map when I use map.layers?

Answer (score 1):

Map.Layers refers to the layer collection in the application's code-behind. You don't need the esri:Map.Layers in your xaml code, because it understands that any child item in the esri:Map xml code will be a layer of some kind of layer.

If you want to manage layers in the code-behind, however, you would use Map.Layers.

XAML:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="Map" >
    <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="samplewebgis" 
          Url="http://m-pc/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer" />        
</esri:Map>
```

Code-behind (VB.net)

```
Dim myLayer as New ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://m-pc/arcgis/rest/services/test2/MapServer")
myLayer.ID = "samplewebgis_2"
Map.Layers.Add(myLayer)
```

Comment: i try your code but still i have same problem .

Answer (score 0):

The first sample is not an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer. It is a tiled map service. Try using `<esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ...`

Writing about spatial software development [spatialexception.org](http://spatialexception.org)

Comment: sorry . i edited my code .

Comment: i try your code . but have same problem . i also installed sp4 for arcgis desktop 10, arcgis server services,arcgis server web application but map legend does not show anything